# Struggling with saving arrays to plist file in Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray, plist

I'm currently implementing the last stage of my first app but having a lot of issues. I'm trying to save the data that has been inputted by the user but I'm finding it extremely confusing.

I was originally using NSUserDefaults which were very easy to understand however I quickly found out that NSMutableArrays could not be stored, so I had to find an alternative. From what I can see storing my five arrays in a plist file would be the best option?

I have done a lot of research on this but there are barely any Swift examples so I have struggled to find a good example to learn from.

At the moment I have set up a plist file 'Transactions.plist' and all that is in it is the preset 'Root'.

This is the code I have for my arrays which is called when users tap an add button:

```
        arrayDataPayments.addObject(transactionName)
        arrayDataCost.addObject(finalUserBudget)
        arrayDataDate.addObject(transactionDateInputted)
        arrayDataValue.addObject(currencyDouble)

        let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Transactions", ofType: "plist")
        arrayDataPayments.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
        arrayDataCost.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
        arrayDataDate.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
        arrayDataValue.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
        arrayDataImage.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
```

Do I need to set anything up in the plist file or can it be left how it is and is my code correct? How can I get each array back from the plist file when I need to display it in my table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can not write to the apps bundle, you want to the the Documents directory.

If the file path was good each `arrayDataPayments.writeToFile` would over-wite the previous. You need to create a plist with all the arrays in it. Or create a Dictionary containing all the arrays and write that file. Each array item would need to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.